# I want to upload 3 differnt file on differnt location in Zend framework2 but I have problem with addfilter

Tags: php, file, file-upload, zend-framework2

Here is my code ,how i am renaming files for differnt paths.My last file share holder is getting upload not uploading first 2.

```
$upload->addFilter('Rename',  $path_memorandum .'/'.$filename_memorandum);
$upload->addFilter('Rename', $path_shareholder1 .'/'. $filename_shareholder1);
$upload->addFilter('Rename', $path_shareholder2 .'/'. $filename_shareholder2);
```

And I tried both approaches like

```
$upload->addFilter('Rename', array(  'target'    => $path_memorandum . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename_memorandum,'overwrite' => true));
$upload->addFilter('Rename', array(  'target'    => $path_shareholder1 . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename_shareholder1,'overwrite' => true));
$upload->addFilter('Rename', array(  'target'    => $path_shareholder2 . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename_shareholder2,'overwrite' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which file the filter is for, if you dont it will assume all files, If you then add multiple filters the last one specified will be used.
Specify the file name for each filter as in the example

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.file.transfer.filters.html

Example

```
$upload = new Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
// Set a new destination path for all files
$upload->addFilter('Rename', 'C:\mypics\new');
// Set a new destination path only for uploadfile1
$upload->addFilter('Rename', 'C:\mypics\newgifs', 'uploadfile1');
```

Comment: I tried below but no luck Andrew,  
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
$upload->addFilter('Rename', $path_memorandum .'/'.$filename_memorandum,'memorandum1')
            ->addFilter('Rename', $path_shareholder1 .'/'. $filename_shareholder1,'shareholders1')
   ->addFilter('Rename', $path_shareholder2 .'/'. $filename_shareholder2,'shareholders2');