# I want to upload 2 files on 2 differnt path on same form using Zend framework 2

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework, zend-framework2

My code is below. Only 2nd file (shareholder1) is getting upload, first file is not getting upload.The problem is with AddFilter..

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
$company_name = $post['idcmpname'];
$douments_path = realpath('companydocuments');
$current_yr = date("Y");
$yr8 = 2018;
$company_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $company_name);
$path_memorandum = $douments_path . '/' . $company_name . '/' . 'memorandum' . '/' . $current_yr;

if (!is_dir($path_memorandum)) {
    mkdir($path_memorandum, 0777, true);
}

$path_shareholder1 = $douments_path . '/' . $company_name . '/' . 'shareholder/' . $yr8;
if (!is_dir($path_shareholder1)) {
    mkdir($path_shareholder1, 0777, true);

    $filename_memorandum = str_replace(' ', '_', $files['memorandum1']['name']);
    $tmpName = $files['memorandum1']['tmp_name'];

    $filename_shareholder1 = str_replace(' ', '_', $files['shareholders1']['name']);
    $tmpName = $files['shareholders1']['tmp_name'];

    $upload->addValidator('Size', false, array('max' => '10MB', 'bytestring' => false));
    $upload->addValidator('Extension', false, array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'pdf', 'txt', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'doc', 'docx', 'rtf'));

    if ($upload->isValid()) {
        $upload->addFilter('Rename', $douments_path . '/' . $company_name . '/' . 'memorandum' . '/' . $current_yr . '/' . $filename_memorandum, 'memorandum1')
            ->addFilter('Rename', $douments_path . '/' . $company_name . '/' . 'shareholder/' . $yr8 . '/' . $filename_shareholder1, 'shareholders1');
    }
}
```

The problem is in AddFilter..I am new to ZF

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to upload 3 differnt file on differnt location in Zend framework2 but I have problem with addfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084392/i-want-to-upload-3-differnt-file-on-differnt-location-in-zend-framework2-but-i-h)

Comment: No .My problem isn't resolved thats why I put it here with code in detail

Comment: Why you didn't update the previous question, then?

Comment: It was too long in comment my friend..if you have checked i haved commented the same there